# I got "No adapter attached; skipping layout" when I put a RecyclerView of TextView's inside a giant CardView

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, cardview

It's supposed to be a resizing searchable RecyclerView of text, since it's just text I decided to put it all in a resizing CardView, is that possible?

I got an error: RecyclerView: No Adapter attached; skipping layout. This is weird because I clearly set my adapter in the AsyncTask onPostExecute. The line

```
((ViewGroup) mDepartmentsView.getParent()).removeView(mDepartmentsView);
```

gets rid of the **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

But now my RecyclerView looks like this when in fact it should have the CardView around the RecyclerView list:

[image: The RecyclerView afterwards]

CirclesFragment:

```
public class CirclesFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = CirclesFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private DepartmentsFragmentBinding mBinding;
private RecyclerView mDepartmentsView;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.departments_fragment, container, false);

    mDepartmentsView = mBinding.departmentsView;
    if (mDepartmentsView.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup) mDepartmentsView.getParent()).removeView(mDepartmentsView);
    }
    new GetDepartmentsAsyncTask(CirclesFragment.this).execute();
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mDepartmentsView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return mDepartmentsView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private class GetDepartmentsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CharSequence, Void, List<Department>> {

    private WeakReference<CirclesFragment> mFragmentRef;

    public GetDepartmentsAsyncTask(CirclesFragment fragment) {
        mFragmentRef = new WeakReference<>(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Department> doInBackground(CharSequence... charSequences) {
        if (mFragmentRef.get() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ArrayList<Department> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(new Department(39762, "ACCT", "Accounting"));
        res.add(new Department(12345, "CS", "Computer Science"));
        res.add(new Department(12350, "ECON", "Economics"));
        res.add(new Department(39762, "ACCT", "Accounting"));
        res.add(new Department(12345, "CS", "Computer Science"));
        res.add(new Department(12350, "ECON", "Economics"));
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Department> departments) {
        super.onPostExecute(departments);
        if (mFragmentRef.get() != null) {
            mFragmentRef.get().getDepartmentsFragmentBinding().departmentsView.setAdapter(new CirclesAdapter(departments));
        }
    }
}

public DepartmentsFragmentBinding getDepartmentsFragmentBinding() {
    return mBinding;
}
```

}

R.layout.departments_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/departments_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

R.layout.department_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="department"
        type="com.skoolar.models.Department">
    </variable>
</data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/inside_padding"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/department_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{department.deptName}"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        tools:text="Title" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/department_abbrev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{department.deptAbbrev}"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        tools:text="Title" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

UPDATE:

When I use the code by ADM user below:, I get this output:

[image]

This was precisely the issue I wanted to avoid at the start. If I just add CardView in row item instead of around RecyclerView in departments_fragments, I still get the same weird layout. I just want the upper and bottom corners to be rounded, I don't want the inbetween corners to be rounded.

Comment: put your java class indicating us the error line

Comment: Add your recycleview's adapter

Comment: share your adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

'The specified child already has a parent' probably happen when you are programmatically add view which already has its parent (added to a view) to another view when any view in android can has only single parent.

Comment: I fixed that, now I got another error, see above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your RecyclerView inside a Layout Under card view :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_analysis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:padding="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/item_mode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And use row item as .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/inside_padding">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/department_name"
            tools:text="Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@{department.deptName}"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/department_abbrev"
            tools:text="Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@{department.deptAbbrev}"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: this is still causing the error. When I put CardView for each row of the RecyclerView, it looks very weird (the cards aren't separated by spaces between, so with the rounded corners, it looks like the recyclerview has bumps along the card

Comment: *I added this not in recycler_view_item_row but in the activity_main one. Could this be problem with data binding?

Comment: department_row.xml does not have card view in question.update the question .

Comment: The output you attached is as expected cause you do not have card view in your row item . See my updated answer .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the recycler veiw inside the card view you try using different layout for the recycler view and the cardview. You can set the items of the cardView in the recycler view using the recycler adapter.